# Why does creating an embedded Derby DB work when testing the code in JUnit, but not when calling it from main method?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, derby

I am trying to create an embedded Derby DB using IntelliJ Ultimate. It works when I test the code using JUnit (I can see the DB folder generate inside my project structure and no error messages are generated), but it does not work when I run the program from the main method. I keep getting the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/derby/iapi/jdbc/JDBCBoot
    at org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver.<clinit>(EmbeddedDriver.java:95)
    at com.github.kyleryvn.taxservice.database.Database.createDatabase(Database.java:26)
    at com.github.kyleryvn.taxservice.Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.iapi.jdbc.JDBCBoot
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 3 more
```

Any idea why this is happening?

My code:

```
public class NewDB {

    public void createDB(String database, String filename) {
        Connection conn;
        PreparedStatement pstmt;
        Statement stmt;
        ResultSet rs;
        String createSQL = "create table " + database + " ("
                + "id integer not null generated always as"
                + " identity (start with 1, increment by 1),   "
                + "name varchar(30) not null, email varchar(30), phone varchar(20),"
                + "constraint primary_key primary key (id))";

        try {
            Driver derbyEmbeddedDriver = new EmbeddedDriver();
            DriverManager.registerDriver(derbyEmbeddedDriver);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:derby:" + database + ";create=true");
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.execute(createSQL);

            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("insert into " + database + " (name,email,phone) values(?,?,?)");
            pstmt.setString(1, "Hagar the Horrible");
            pstmt.setString(2, "hagar@somewhere.com");
            pstmt.setString(3, "(123) 456-7890");
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from " + database);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.printf("%d %s %s %sn",
                        rs.getInt(1), rs.getString(2),
                        rs.getString(3), rs.getString(4));
            }

            conn.commit();

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.out.println("in connection" + ex);
        }

        try {
            DriverManager.getConnection
                    ("jdbc:derby:;shutdown=true");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            if (((ex.getErrorCode() == 50000) &&
                    ("XJ015".equals(ex.getSQLState())))) {
                System.out.println("\nDerby shut down normally");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Derby did not shut down normally");
                System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maven dependencies:

```
<derby.version>10.15.2.0</derby.version>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
   <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
   <version>${derby.version}</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
   <artifactId>derbytools</artifactId>
   <version>${derby.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: `<scope>test</scope>`

Comment: Remove the scope limited to test.

Comment: Wow, I feel so stupid for missing that small detail. Thank you all!